Nuxt 3 Route Groups and Layout Issues with Route Groups
I'm trying to create a layout that applies only to pages within a specific route group in Nuxt 3, but I'm running into several issues with different approaches.
Current Setup
My current directory structure:
-| pages/
---| index.vue
---| somepage.vue
---| (marketing)/
-----| contact.vue
-----| about.vue

What I've Tried
Attempt 1: Using layout.vue in the route group
-| pages/
---| index.vue
---| somepage.vue
---| (marketing)/
-----| layout.vue      # Tried this
-----| contact.vue
-----| about.vue

Issue: layout.vue creates its own route (/layout), which is not what I want.
Attempt 2: Using default.vue as a wrapper
-| pages/
---| index.vue
---| somepage.vue
---| (marketing)/
-----| default.vue    # Tried this
-----| contact.vue
-----| about.vue

Issue: Similar to layout.vue, this creates an unwanted /default route.
Attempt 3: Using index.vue as a parent layout
-| pages/
---| index.vue
---| somepage.vue    # Unexpectedly affected by (marketing)/index.vue
---| (marketing)/
-----| index.vue     # Tried this: Should act as a parent layout for marketing pages only
-----| contact.vue   # Expected to inherit (marketing)/index.vue as a layout
-----| about.vue     # Expected to inherit (marketing)/index.vue as a layout

Issue: This creates a route and doesn't work as a layout wrapper.
Expected Behavior
I want to:

Have a specific layout that applies ONLY to pages within the (marketing) route group
Keep the URL structure clean (no additional routes)
Not have to manually add definePageMeta({ layout: 'marketing' }) to every page in the marketing group
Ensure pages outside the route group (like somepage.vue) are not affected by the marketing layout

Question
How can I create a layout that automatically applies to all pages within a route group in Nuxt 3 without:

Creating additional routes
Manually setting the layout in each file
Affecting pages outside the route group

Is there a proper way to handle this use case in Nuxt 3?
Additional Notes

Route Groups (with parentheses) are being used to organize routes without affecting the URL structure
The standard layouts system works but requires manual configuration for each page
Looking for a DRY solution that maintains clean URLs and proper route organization

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
